# Conditional annotate on django 1.8 queryset

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models

I have a model that looks something like the following:

```
class MyStat(Model):
     metric = ForeignKey(MetricType) 
     source = ForeingKey(SourceType)

     total_units = IntegerField()
     metric_units = IntegerField()

     objects = MyQuerySet().as_manager()
```

The query does the following within a piece of its code

```
rollup = self.order_by().values(source.name)\.
                 annotate(mu=Sum('metric_units'), tu=Sum('total_units'))
```

And this works great.  However, I would like to modify some of those annotation dependent on the `metric` type that is used.  Somehow, create a database side conditional that will annotate slightly differently (pseudo code below):

```
if metric is some_metric:
      .annotate(mu=.8*Sum('metric_units'))
else:
      .annotate(mu=Sum('metric_units'))
```

Obviously the above syntax is invalid, but I'm wondering if there is a way to set up my queryset to do something like that on the database side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make conditional expresions with [`Case`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#case).

Let's go to the annotate part.

**Disclaimer: This code is untested**

```
from django.db.models import Case, Value, When, FloatField, Sum

...annotate(mu=Case(When(metric=some_metric, then=Value(.8*Sum('metric_units')),
                    default=Value(Sum('metric_units')),
                    output_field=FloatField())))
```

If you need to match against multiple values in a list, you can create a list of `When` objects:

```
whens = []
for some_metric in some_metrics:
    whens.append(When(metric=some_metric, then=Value(some-value-here)))

...annotate(mu=Case(*whens, default=Value(Sum('metric_units')),
                            output_field=FloatField()))
```

Comment: quick following up, how can you make the case when there are multiple metrics you want to apply the condition to?  I tried doing `metric__in=some_metrics` with no success.

Comment: @sedavidw is `some_metrics` a list? Have you tried if this code works with only one value to match the condition -> `metric=some_metric` ?

Comment: It is a list, I have tried with the single and that works.  Looking through the docs it looks like I can string `When` objects together within the `Case` to achieve that effect

Comment: forgot there was one small typo, just edited the answer

Comment: You're right it is `default`, thanks. I hope this helped you.